# JQuery dialog closing lag if behind new browser window

Tags: jquery

Clicking a hyperlink on one of my pages opens a JQuery dialog.
Clicking the Cancel-button closes the dialog.
Clicking the Confirm-button closes the dialog and opens the URL of the clicked hyperlink in a new browser window.

This works, but when closing the new browser window, the dialog (that should have been closed already) can still be seen during a split second.
This happens most of the times in Chrome 46 (on Windows 7), but not always. The lag is even longer in Chrome on Android.
It happens too in Opera 33, but not as often and not as long as in Chrome.
In IE 11 as well as in the native browser of my Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, I couldn't reproduce the issue, it works like it should.

I'm looking for a workaround for this issue...

http://jsfiddle.net/myt661hz/

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required" style="display: none;">
    Continue to your preferred technology site?
</div>
<a class="confirmLink" href="http://www.techradar.com" target="_blank">Techradar</a> OR
<a class="confirmLink" href="http://www.trustedreviews.com" target="_blank">Trusted reviews</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
    });
});

$(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            window.open(targetUrl, '_blank');
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Instead of closing it use to `destroy` it. Otherwise there will be multiple instances of it on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the `window.open` call in `setTimeout` to give the call its own thread.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  window.open(targetUrl, '_blank');
}, 0);
```

This should keep the dialog close action from being blocked by the appearance and focus of a new browser tab.

The zero passed in to `setTimeout` causes it to execute immediately.

---

**--- EDIT ---**

Using `window.open` inside `setTimeout` causes IE to prompt the user to confirm they want the window to open.

To avoid calling `window.open` inside `setTimeout` try opening the window using the `close` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      open: function( event, ui ) {
        // ensure 'targetUrl' is cleared on open
        $(this).data('targetUrl', null);
      },
      close: function( event, ui ) {
        // if 'targetUrl' has been set, open in new window
        var targetUrl = $(this).data('targetUrl');
        if(targetUrl) {
          $(this).data('targetUrl', null);
          window.open(targetUrl, '_blank');
        }
      }
    });
});

$(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            $(this).data('targetUrl', targetUrl).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).data('targetUrl', null).dialog("close");
        }
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Thanks csum, it looks like the original problem is gone in Chrome, but adding the setTimeout function gives another problem in IE11 now. Because of the setTimeout function, IE asks if it's OK to display a popup (something I want to avoid).

Comment: @Flippi I edited my answer to use `open` and `close` event handlers. Perhaps this workaround addresses the IE issue by avoiding the call to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Still having issues, even with the last script you provided. I'll do some more tests tomorrow. Best result until now still is the `SetTimeout` function, except for IE, but I could do something like `if IE { window.open } else { setTimeout window.open }`

Comment: Just found some time to test it thoroughly. Using the code above (opening the window using the close handler) brought me back to the original problem: fine in IE, but lag in Chrome and Opera. I decided to use the `setTimeout` solution, except for IE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myt661hz/21/). With `setTimeout = 0` there still was some lag in Chrome on Android. Setting `setTimeout` to 100 gives the browser more time to close the dialog before opening a new window. However don't put this value too high because it would make Chrome think the window is a popup and then it will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

both action happens ||ly so before close the dialog it opens window. browser behariour that DOM may update only when it focus. to avoid with setTimeout with required time delay. also refer  jsfiddle link below.

`$(this).dialog("close");
setTimeout(function(){window.open(targetUrl, '_blank');},1);`

http://jsfiddle.net/myt661hz/8/

Comment: Thanks Manivannan, it works, but now IE considers clicking the Confirm-button as invoking a popup (something that wasn't the case without the setTimeout function).

Comment: Oh, I dont have IE right now, normally sush security check will be there while opening new tab through scripts, ll double check & update u after a while